# How do I specify the compression level of a zip file in python?

Tags: python, zip

How do I zip a file in python and how do specify the compression level ?

I have the below code so far and the error I get is:

```
Zip("log4j.dl-service.log.2013-05-03-22",9)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ZipFile'
```

Code:

```
import zipfile
import fileinput

def Zip(file,level):
    """
    This function uses the zip library native to python to compress files with
    Usage: Zip(file,level)
    """

    if file and level:
        try:
            zipfile = file+'.zip'
            output = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfile, 'wb')
            for line in fileinput.input(file):
                output.write(line)
            output.close()
            if os.path.exists(zipfile):
                return zipfile
            else:
                logMe('critical',"zip failed in Zip()")
                return False

        except Exception,e:
            logMe('critical',e)
```

Comment: A: Don't use variable names that are the same as your imports that's just asking for trouble.
B: Don't use variable names that are the same as your imports it makes it impossible to read.
C: Don't use variable names that are the same as your imports.

Comment: @JeffLangemeier: You should write that as an answer (with a bit more info), because… well, it's the answer.

Comment: @SimplySeth: Please post a the whole traceback, not just the error message. We can guess pretty easily in this case, because there happens to be only one place where you try to access an attribute named `ZipFile` on anything, but why make us guess?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is this line:

```
zipfile = file+'.zip'
```

After that, `zipfile` no longer refers to the module, but to this string. So, when you do this:

```
output = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfile, 'wb')
```

You're asking a string, not a module, to call `ZipFile`.

Hence this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ZipFile'
```

The fix is to not call your variable `zipfile`.

As Jeff Langemeier says, the key is:

> Don't use variable names that are the same as your imports that's just asking for trouble. B: Don't use variable names that are the same as your imports it makes it impossible to read. C: Don't use variable names that are the same as your imports.

More generally, don't use the same name for two different things.

---

For your second question:

> how do specify the compression level

You can't. This is intentional, for the same reason that the `zip` command-line tool no longer documents 10 levels of compression, just `-0` for store (no compression), and `-9` for "compress better". There's almost never any good use for anything but store or the default. `-9` often doesn't really compress better than the default—or it compresses some files better and others worse. If you need better compression, you need a better algorithm—e.g., use `.tar.bz2` instead of `.zip`, or use `p7zip` (which can create zip-compatible files) instead of plain `zip`.

So, Python's library only gives you two choices: store or default. As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile) show:

> `class zipfile.ZipFile(file[, mode[, compression[, allowZip64]]])`
>
> …
>
> compression is the ZIP compression method to use when writing the archive, and should be ZIP_STORED or ZIP_DEFLATED

And likewise for the `write`/`writestr` methods.

If you really want to do this, you can call `zlib.compress` directly, create a `ZipInfo` object directly, and add it to the archive yourself. If you look at [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/zipfile.py#l1196) (which is linked from the docs), you can see what `writestr` does—it's really not complicated once you strip out all the irrelevant conditions and type checks.

But really, I don't think you want to do this.

Comment: I only added this because I thought @JeffLangemeier wasn't going to answer. I was going to delete it, but now it's been upvoted twice. I guess it provides some extra explanation, but Jeff found the problem and provided the answer first.

Comment: Personally, I like yours better, I couldn't quite articulate the answer as cleanly.

Comment: @JeffLangemeier: I thought "Don't use variable names that are the same as your imports" was pretty clear. And I like the repetition, with different reasons each time.

Comment: it was a sad case of cerebral flatulence on my behalf. 
Thank you.

Comment: I guess I get to be the "Dr. Seussian Fight Club" answerer then.

Comment: apparently my cerebral flatulence continues, because I can't find in the documentation where to state the compression level (1-9)

Comment: @SimplySeth: You can't state the compression level, which is actually 0-9 not 1-9, you can only give it 0 or default. But what makes you think you need this? I can't remember a case since the mid-90s where default was too big but `zip -9` was small enough, or where default was too slow but `zip -1` was fast enough. (And that was more about the old "implode" algorithm sucking than about 800K disks being small and Pentiums being slow.)

Answer (score 7):

So I guess my comment is the answer as well.

Your variables are essentially "overloading" the calls to the imported methods, making for some really bad munging of your code.  So follow these rules:

A: Don't use variable names that are the same as your imports that's just asking for trouble.

B: Don't use variable names that are the same as your imports it makes it impossible to read.

C: Don't use variable names that are the same as your imports.

It'll save you and the people you ask a lot of headache if you follow this. If, you do so choose to make it close, use an underscore to separate zip_file, or filezip, or anything else.